# Converting TicTacToe game in Blazor to .Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I have retrieved a code from thee following GitHub link https://github.com/exceptionnotfound/BlazorWasmTicTacToe

The code behind that is a Tic Tac Toe Game developed using **Blazor WASM**. I want to try and use he's code to develop a similar one using .Net Core MVC (3.1). So basically i have created the models as per the main Blazor source code but on running, the Index.cshtml is not responsive.
[image: It loads the grid full of 'x' instead of blank]

Below is my View(Index.cshtml)

```
@using TicTacGame.Models;
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Tic Tac Toe";
GameBoard board = new GameBoard();
}

@if (!board.GameComplete)
{
<h2>@board.CurrentTurn's turn</h2>
}
else
{
<h2>
    @board.GetMessage()
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="@{board.Reset();} ">New Game</button>
</h2>
}

<div class="board">
@for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    <div class="column">
        @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            int x = i;
            int y = j;
            <div class="gamepiece
                @board.Board[i, j].Style.ToString().ToLower()" onclick=@{ board.PieceClicked(x, y);}
                 style="@(board.IsGamePieceAWinningPiece(i,j)?"opacity:0.1": "")"></div>

        }
    </div>
}
```

My controller is a basic:
`return View();`

Where am I going wrong as compared to almost the same code in Blazor working.

Comment: Blazor is so much better for games than MVC. Your conversion makes no sense.

Comment: I know, it's a great challenge to undertake. @Henk

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `onclick=@{ board.PieceClicked(x, y);}` with Blazor this will run on the in the page on the client.

In ASP.Net MVC, however, this view will be rendered on the server and `board` won't be available and therefore cannot be run on the client. You will have to migrate the `PieceClicked` code to TypeScript/JavaScript so that it has something to run client side in when clicked.

Of course, this also means that you will have to migrate `board.Reset()` too.

Comment: Any Open source Repository you know of?

Comment: The existing code (C#) will be in the project. You'll need to convert that to the appropriate JavaScript.

Comment: What if the game states were stored in variables